# Is it possible to embed fonts in a .cdf?

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use a special font with musical symbols in a .cdf that I send to some friends. The font is called "Tempera" and is freely distributed here:

http://christian.texier.pagespro-orange.fr/mididesi/free/index.htm#tempera

In the .cdf I use substitutions like this:

```
sub = "A" -> "\*StyleBox[\(\!\(\*StyleBox[\"A\",\n\
   FontFamily->\"Mathematica6\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\"U\",\n\
   FontFamily->\"Tempera\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\"]\)\)]";
```

which are used in this manner:

```
 "A" //. sub
```

What this does is to change the regular "A" character into a curly A (from the Mathematica6 font) and a symbol that is a half-sharp (the "U" from the Tempera font). This works fine in Mathematica, and also in the .cdf on my computer. However, when I send it to my friend, he sees the "U" and not the half-flat. This is probably what you will see too, unless you download the Tempera font. I believe this means that Mathematica does not embed the font in the .cdf, and I'm wondering if there is any way to force the embedding to occur. While I could have my friend download the font, if I ever want to place the .cdf on the web, this would not be practical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mathematica will only let you use fonts installed on the system. 
I have two suggestions here:

1. At the top of your CDF file, display a link depending on the operating system, pointing to the correct file for downloading the font

   ```
   link = If[$OperatingSystem == "Linux" || $OperatingSystem == "Windows", 
       Hyperlink["Download font for " <> $OperatingSystem , "http://christian.texier.pagespro-orange.fr/mididesi/free/media/tempera.zip"],
               Hyperlink["Download font for Mac", "http://christian.texier.pagespro-orange.fr/mididesi/free/media/electronica.sit"]
   ];
   link
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can create PDFs for the single characters you use. Out of them, you can create a textual representation which can be saved within your CDF file:

   ```
   pdfA = Import["tempera_a.pdf"][[1]];
   symbolA = Compress[pdfA]
   ```

   with the outputs from `Compress[]` you can maybe create a list for the alphabet you use.
   When you want to use the font afterwards, you can do

   ```
   "A"/.{"A" -> Uncompress[symbolA]}
   ```

Edit: For the latter approach, I just noticed that Mathematica does have severe problems with embedded fonts - they are not showing up in the correct font. I guess using a raster format like PNG instead of PDF would work, but it's not as nice as scalable fonts from a PDF. If you use PNG however, the files will stay small enough to be included, even at a relatively high resolution. I checked this with a PNG file with resolution 1000px*1000px, where the file size was 60kib, compared to 300kb for the PDF file with the same character and embedded font.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the answer to my question is really quite simple: "no, it is not possible to embed fonts in a .cdf". Thanks to Ulrik for the ideas for work-arounds, and what I ended up doing is closely related to his second suggestion: to create a rasterized graphic element for each symbol that is needed. For instance, for the half-sharp of the original question, this is:

```
halfSharp = Rasterize["\*StyleBox[\"U\",\nFontFamily->\"Tempera\",
       \nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\"]"];
```

Now, whenever the half-sharp symbol is needed, it can be displayed using the variable name halfSharp. This can also be made into a handy function:

```
rasterizeLetters[let_, font_] := ImagePad[Rasterize[Style[let, 
     FontFamily -> font, FontSize -> 100]], 10, White]
```

so the same image-symbol can now be created

```
halfSharp = rasterizeLetters["U","Tempera"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation on part 2 of Ulrik's answer, which works on my system (Mac) with the Tempera font.  One can bypass file generation with `ExportString` and `ImportString`; the results can be stored in the CDF notebook.  The result of each `Import` is `Graphics`, not a formatted `String`.  Consequently all the font information is lost (e.g. kerning, baseline position) as well as other font advantages (e.g. smoothing).  One the other hand, the graphics (at least in this case) are scalable.

**Creating the images**

There are two primary functions, `temperaSign` for a single music sign and `graphicsForm` for a combination of a letter and sign as in the OP's question; the auxiliary function `combine` creates a text-based combination of a letter and sign like the OP's example.

`````
temperaSign[sign_] := 
  First @ ImportString[ExportString[Style[sign, FontFamily -> "Tempera"], "PDF"], "PDF"];

combine[letter_, sign_] := 
 StringForm["````", Style[letter, FontFamily -> "Mathematica6"], 
  Style[sign, FontFamily -> "Tempera", FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> "Plain"]]; 
temperaForm[letter_, sign_] := 
 First @ ImportString[ExportString[combine[letter, sign], "PDF"], "PDF"]
`````

Here's what the imported `Graphics` look like:

```
temperaSign["U"] // InputForm
  (* Graphics[{Thickness[0.6361323155216285], 
      Style[{FilledCurve[{{{0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0},
          {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}}, 
         {{{0.01200488090515137, 6.366542406082154}, {0.01200488090515137, 5.374395179748535},
          ... 10 points omitted ...
          {0.01200488090515137, 6.366542406082154}}}]}, 
       Thickness[0.6361323155216285]]}, 
     ImageSize -> {2., 12.}, PlotRange -> {{0., 1.572}, {0., 12.}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic] *)
```

To get good size and positioning, one has to play with `ImageSize` and `BaselinePosition`.  Close inspection shows the size is slightly off.

```
Row[{combine["A", "U"], 
  Show[temperaSign["U"], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 24}, BaselinePosition -> Scaled[0.41]]}]
```

[image: Text, graphics sharp]

Here is a somewhat high-resolution rendering comparing the text, graphics, and rasterized versions.  (At screen resolution, the rasterized version is only slightly fuzzy.)

```
{combine["A", "U"], 
 Show[graphicsForm["A", "U"], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 24}, 
  BaselinePosition -> Scaled[0.37]],
 Rasterize@combine["A", "U"]}
```

[image: Text, graphics, raster]

**Creating the database**

One can compute all of the signs to be used and store them in a notebook.
For instance:

```
m[#] -> temperaSign[#] & /@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"]
```

Then type `sub =` and copy the output:

[image: Substitution rules]

Here I used `m` as a wrapper; you might wish to use a more expressive symbol such as `musicSign` (but beware reusing `temperaSign`).  Or you may wish to use letter-strings (`"A" ->...`).

One could process music text with something like:

```
baselineAdjust[m["U"]] = Scaled[0.37];
baselineAdjust[m["A"]] = Scaled[0.16];
  (* add more baseline defs as desired *)
baselineAdjust[_] := Center;
temperaAdjust[expr_Graphics, opts___] := Show[expr, opts];
temperaAdjust[expr_] /; Head[expr] =!= m := 
  expr /. sign_m :> temperaAdjust[sign, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 24}, 
                                        BaselinePosition -> baselineAdjust[sign]];

note = {"A", m["U"]};
temperaAdjust @ Row[note, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Mathematica6"}] /. sub
```

[image: A half sharp]

```
note = {"B", m["A"]};
temperaAdjust @ Row[note, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Mathematica6"}] /. sub
```

[image: B flat]