# How can I type in math calligraphy letters?

Tags: formatting

I cannot find this kind of letters in the pallete.

[image]

math calligraphy?

I can only find this in Mathemtica.

[image]

Comment: In the nomenclature of $\LaTeX$, what you're showing would be called `\mathscr` or "math script," whereas `\mathcal` (or "calligraphy") is what *Mathematica* already has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it if your system has a script font available. In my case, I chose for example `Bickham Script Pro` (from Adobe, I got it with the purchase of some other software). You'll have to look around on your computer or on the web for a matching font. It's not part of the standard installation on my computer, so I can only ask you to find it yourself.

Assuming this step is completed, here is an example:

[image: text]

To enter the script letter in the inline equation, I typed the `C` and the rest of the equation, then highlighted `C` and used the menu item `Show Fonts` to select the script font. I had to adjust the font size to match the surrounding sizes visually,  and that's all.

**Edit**

To address the problem mentioned in Bill's comment, you could use the function `toPDF` I defined in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26303/245) in order to produce outlined paths from the fonts. Then the result can be exported and read by anyone, no matter whether they have the fonts installed or not. Just use `Export["file.pdf", toPDF["..."]]` where `...` is the text with all necessary fonts as shown above.

Comment: Beware (or be careful) with adding fonts. As we find out here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20590/is-it-possible-to-embed-fonts-in-a-cdf you cannot export these fonts for use by people who don't have them on their computers, though there are some work-arounds.

Comment: @bills See my edit. You can outline the fonts. In `CDF`, the text can then be used in the form of a (resolution-independent) `Graphics` object.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
 lst = Cases[
   FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]], _Rule];
lst2 = Replace[lst, (x_ -> y_) -> x, 2];
lst3 = Append[
  Delete[Select[lst2, 
    MemberQ[Characters[#], "S"] && MemberQ[Characters[#], "c"] && 
      MemberQ[Characters[#], "r"] && MemberQ[Characters[#], "i"] && 
      MemberQ[Characters[#], "p"] && MemberQ[Characters[#], "t"] &], 
   5], "Mathematica5"]
```

will bring up a list of the script fonts found already on your machine. In my case the result is:

```
 {"Brush Script MT", "Freestyle Script", "Kunstler Script", "Matura MT \
Script Capitals", "Script", "Vladimir Script", "Mathematica5"}
```

This:

```
 Column@Table[
  Style["Font Family -> " <> lst3[[i]], 30, 
   FontFamily -> lst3[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[lst3]}]
```

will show up examples of these scripts to choose one of your liking.

Comment: I am sorry to wake you up again, but how to see this in Mathematica 11.0.1.0.

Comment: Well, I did not sleep yet. Replace ` "Mathematica5"` for ` "Mathematica11"`and evaluate.